# angular empty var using shared service between components

Tags: angular

I'm having problems when I need to use some data between components in an Angular project. I read that using a shared data service is a good option to do it so I'm trying to implement this but I can't.

In the beginning of the project I'm getting some categories from a http request.
these categories need to be used in the header and in the body of the project.
So I'm getting the categories in the app.component.ts

```
constructor(
    public _categoryService: CategoryService,
    private _dataService: DataService
  ){
    this.getCategories();
  }

  getCategories(){
    this._categoryService.getCategories().subscribe(
      response => {
        if(response.status == 'success'){
          this.categories = response.categories;
          this._dataService.setCategories(this.categories);

          let categories = this._dataService.getCategories();
          console.log(categories);
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
  }
```

app.component.html

```
    <app-header [categories]="categories"></app-header>
 
    <!-- CONTENT -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  
    <app-footer></app-footer>
```

In the header I'm listing the categories without problem. But I want to list them in the categories page component.
I can't add the categories in the  that's why I'm using the _dataService.

But when I click in the categories routerlink

```
// ROUTES DEFINITIONS
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: PageHomeComponent },
    { path: 'categories', component: PageCategoriesComponent },
];
```

I can't get the categories in the PageCategoriesComponent

```
constructor(
    private _dataService: DataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let categories = this._dataService.getCategories();
    console.log(categories);
  }
```

In the Chrome console I'm seeing how the first console.log is that of the page-categories-component with null value and the second console.log is that of the app.component with all the categories.

Please, can someone explain me what is happening?

**EDIT**
I've added a button in the page-categories.component.html to be sure the request in the app.component has finished and the categories are loaded in the dataService, But it still returns an empty array

```
<button (click)="clickButton()">get categories</button>
```

page-categories.component.ts

```
clickButton(){
    this._dataService.getCategories().subscribe((data) => {
      this.categories = data;
      console.log(this.categories);
    });
  }
```

**SOLUTION**
I've added this in the DataService:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  private bSubject = new BehaviorSubject([]);

    getCategories() {
        return this.bSubject.asObservable();
    }

    setCategories(value: any) {
        return this.bSubject.next(value);
    }
}
```

And also I removed the DataService from the providers in the component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-categories',
  templateUrl: './page-categories.component.html',
  styleUrl: './page-categories.component.css',
  providers: []
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

ensure you have providedIn: 'root' set in the service and ensure you have not added the service to any providers array, this will cause a separate instance to be added, its crucial that all components share the same instance export class test {} -> definition, new test() -> instance of class (this needs to be a singleton!)

---

The get categories is an asynchronous method `getCategories` since the first `console.log` is inside the subscribe the console.log is giving you values, but asyncronous means the rest of the code executes irrespective of the subscribe being completed. So I would recommend two solutions

1. Although you are seeing null when you `console.log`, if you expand the array in the console log you will see the values are actually present (if you are not creating a new array when you get the values), so you have access to the other values, without doing anything, you can run the array through an `*ngFor` or `{{categories | json}}` and check if the values are present. try `this.categories = this._dataService.getCategories();` since we need to store the variable on the class property for it to be visible on the html
2. You can use a behaviour subject, which will hold the last emitted value and we can subscribe to the latest value

service

```
export class DataService {
    private bSubject = new BehaviourSubject([]);

    getCategories() {
        return this.bSubject.asObservable();
    }

    setCategories(value: any) {
        return this.bSubject.next(value);
    }
    ...
```

component

```
...
categories: any =[];

ngOnInit() {
    this._dataService.getCategories().subscribe((data) => {
        this.categories = data;
        console.log(categories);
    });
}
...
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response! 
I've followed the 2 points that you mentioned and from the Component page I still receive an empty observable. I suppose it is because the onInit of the Page component is executed when the getCategories of the AppComponent has not yet finished collecting the response...

That's why I've done a quick test. I've included a button in the page-component with the function to collect the categories (already loaded in the data service) but I still receive an empty observable...

Comment: @maued please shar a stackblitz with the issue replicated

Comment: @maued ensure you have `providedIn: 'root'` set in the service and ensure you have not added the service to any providers array, this will cause a separate instance to be added, its crucial that all components share the same instance `export class test {}` -> definition, `new test()` -> instance of class (this needs to be a singleton!)

Comment: that's it Naren! Indeed, I didn't  add the providedIn: 'root' in the service and I added the DataService as a provider in each component. Now I understand well what was happening. Thanks for your help.